# Apache logging based on user agent

Tags: apache, logging, user-agent, apache-log-files

I'd like to update my apache logging so that its destination is based on the user agent string or file type.

Specifically, I would like to send my googlebot requests to their own log file, and I would like to not log requests for any of my image files.

My configuration is pretty much stock.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding something like the following into your VirtualHost config:

```
SetEnvIf User-agent .*Googlebot.* googlebot
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access_googlebot.log combined env=googlebot
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined env=!googlebot
```

Comment: In reference to the reply by Ewan, When you refer to VirtualHost config would that be the apache2.conf, the httpd.conf, or other file?